# Updating XML value within MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

replacing XML tag value within a large XML text value MSSQL.

Within MSSQL I have a column called form which is a text column with an extremely large XML. I need to find a certain tag and change the value of that sub tag within the tag from False to True.

This is what I currently have:

```
USE trainset;
UPDATE dbo.users 
SET formxml = REPLACE(CAST(formxml as nvarchar(max)), '%<ttaycheckbox><name>cbTermsConditions</name><cargo>F</cargo></ttaycheckbox>%', '<ttaycheckbox><name>cbTermsConditions</name><cargo>T</cargo></ttaycheckbox>')

WHERE usersid = '0000GARX'
and formname ='ffOrderRpt'
and formxml LIKE ('%<ttaycheckbox><name>cbTermsConditions</name><cargo>F</cargo></ttaycheckbox>%')
```

It seems like it is doing the update;
However, after this when I do a select on this particular value the value of  is still False rather than True.

What am I missing in there that is not causing it to update properly?

Comment: It is - in almost all cases - a bad approach to cast existing XML to a string type, modify it there and cast it back. This might have side effects (e.g. swallow `CDATA` sections). You should, if ever possible, use the *real* XML methods, in this case `.modify()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` doesn't support wildcards. So your `where ... like` finds the relevant records, but `replace` finds NOTHING, because it's looking for a literal `%`.

Comment: Ahhh okay that explains it....so how would I go about doing this? because I only need to replace the sub-string in there.

Comment: `replace('<foo>1</foo>', '<foo>0</foo')`, exactly like that. simply DON'T put wildcards into the replace statement. You already limited the records that replace() can work on via the `where ... like` filtering anyways.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML [modify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) and [exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx):

```
UPDATE users 
SET formxml.modify('replace value of (/ttaycheckbox/cargo/text())[1] with "T"')
WHERE usersid = '0000GARX'
and formname ='ffOrderRpt'
and formxml.exist('/ttaycheckbox/name[text()[1] eq "cbTermsConditions"]') = 1 
and formxml.exist('/ttaycheckbox/cargo[text()[1] eq "F"]') = 1
```